# Javascript event to fire on databindin in textbox

Tags: javascript

In My grid, text box is having events of Onblur and onchange, while entering manually both the events are getting triggered in client side, but while binding from database events not triggered. Is there any specific event to call while binding the data. Working in MVC & java script.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyModel>()
.Name("gridCreateInput")
.Columns(columns =>
{ 
columns.Bound(p => p.decBillAmt).Width(250).Title("Bill Amount").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "templatedrp" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @style = "text-align:right" })
.ClientTemplate(Html.TextBox("numeric", "#=decBillAmt#", new { onblur = "'return onBlurBillAmount(this);'", onchange = "'return onchangeBillAmount(this);'"}).ToHtmlString())
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "DecimalFontStyle", @style = "text-align : right;" });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Perhaps some code that isn't working?  [How to ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what do you mean by _binding from database_

Comment: it could be anything or nothing, please share some code

Comment: @AlexMcMillan, surendar & ST i have shared my code.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan : while entering manual input (key press events) both events triggering. Same case while binding data to grid from db it's not happening.